# Remove .css () jQuery when clicking on other div (addClass doesn't work properly)

Tags: jquery, css, background

I am trying to create some simple buttons. I have managed to get a Jquery code which on click changes the css attributes.
here the code:

```
>     $(document).ready(function(){ 
>       $(".but1").click(function(){
>         $(this).css("background-color","white");
>         $(this).css("font-size", "9px");
>       
>       });
>       
>     });
```

Now, how can I make it that it removes the code when i click on another object?

I have found this:

```
 $(this).css("background-color", "")
```

but how can I use?

I know that it can be done with something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".men1").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("my class").siblings().removeClass("my class");
  }); 
});
```

however, it seems that in my web i cannot get the background to work just width and height...

how can I solve this????

Comment: Piece of advice, a class like `my class` is not a CSS class. It contains a space.

Comment: Fix the CSS problem instead. This isn't a good way to use `.css()`.

Comment: work with classes, not with inline/jquery CSS. And, like Hidde said, classes cannot have spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `background-color` and `font-size` properties are CSS properties. With jQuery (and the normal JavaScript `object.style` attributes), use the `backgroundColor` and `fontSize` properties.

Like this:

`$(this).css('fontSize', 16);`

`$(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "transparent" as a valid css background color, which will "remove" the color. Also, you may want to try using the #FFF hex syntax for your colors, although both white and #FFF should work. A lot of great information here, and read all the way down, because it gives the best examples towards the middle. This is what I use to fix things like this.

[jQuery css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)